# Type conversion from data class to recyclerView

Tags: android, json, kotlin, mvvm

There is a JSON response:

```
{
    "response" : [
        {
            "f_name"    : "иВан",
            "l_name"    : "ИваноВ",
            "birthday"  : "1987-03-23",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {
            "f_name"    : "Петр",
            "l_name"    : "петроВ",
            "birthday"  : null,
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
       }
    ]
}
```

and the corresponding data class in the model:

```
data class EmployeesInfo( val response: List<Response> )

data class Response(
    @SerializedName("avatr_url")
    val avatrUrl: String,
    val birthday: String,
    @SerializedName("f_name")
    val fName: String,
    @SerializedName("l_name")
    val lName: String,
    val specialty: List<Specialty>
)
data class Specialty(
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("specialty_id")
    val specialtyId: Int
)
```

Those. it turns out the EmployeesInfo class is a list of type Response.And in the constructor of the Response class there is a specialty field, which, judging by the square brackets, is also a list (in it the 1st element is specialty_id, the 2nd is name). And I just need to form a list of these names from all objects of the Response array and give them to the adapter so that they are displayed in the RecyclerView ..How can i do this? Maybe i need to use map function ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be acheived using flatMap:

```
 response.flatMap { it -> it.specialty.map { it.name } }
```

Comment: You can replace `specialty.flatMap { listOf(it.name) } ` with `specialty.map { it.name }`. That will probably make more sense.

Comment: Yes you're right